# Spring caching of pojo getters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, ehcache

I'm working on an auction system where the price value of a product has to be recalculated every n minutes. 
I've successfully implemented ehcache with spring boot on my controller and service levels, now i'm going to cache some model superclass getters but @Cacheable doesn't work with the getCurrentPrice() method (I tried also specifying cache name and key).
Maybe Spring cache is not designed for this aim? I have to manage cache manually for getPrice(), use a custom cache, or I'm doing something wrong?

```
public abstract class PricedEntity{

public abstract void getInfo();

@Cacheable
public Price getCurrentPrice(){}
//...my code here...long task computation(about 0.3 seconds) 
//the price is variable every 5/10 minutes due to bid/ask and USD/EUR change value
```

}
}

Comment: PricedEntity should be a spring bean, if it is a simple POJO then it will not work I think

Comment: Thanks, that was my guess, too. So I'm forced to implement a pojo cache layer manually.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added @EnableCaching to your Spring Boot application configuration? Like here:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: yes, the caching system already works well with controller, service and mapper methods.

Answer (score 0):

I should work. What annotations do you have on your class? `@Cacheable` can clash with `@Async` for instance.

Also, it needs to be called from the outside. You can't do `this.getCurrentPrice()`. It won't go through the proxy doing the caching.

Answer (score 0):

@Cacheable is meant to work on Spring managed beans. It will work on a class that you instantiate by yourself.

Either move price calculation to a separate component to and make it cacheable or memoize calculated value after first method invocation.